# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Transition types

Tags: android, exception, android-4.4-kitkat, transition

Recently i have got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Transition types`.
This exception happens on android api 19 and it appeared after i have updated android build tools and support libraries to version 27.

Does anyone know what has changed with KitKat transitions?

```
    Fragment fragment = new  Fragment();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Transition transition = new AutoTransition();
        fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
    }

    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.addSharedElement(view, "TransitionView");
    ft.replace(R.id.mainActivity_container, fragment, backStateName);
    ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
    ft.commit();
```

Full exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Transition types
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.chooseImpl(FragmentTransition.java:461)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsOrdered(FragmentTransition.java:3317)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2380)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

**UPDATE**

After changing from `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)` to `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` I don't get exception.

Answer (score 19):

You are mixing transitions from androidx (the support library) and the platform.
For example.:

```
import androidx.transition.AutoTransition;
import android.transition.Fade;
```

(note the missing 'x')

Change that to only use support library, like this:

```
import androidx.transition.AutoTransition;
import androidx.transition.Fade;
```

Comment: In my case I was mixing `androidx.*` transitions with `android.*` transitions

Comment: Thanks @AdamJohns. Ive changed the answer to androidx

Comment: Made my day. Thanks! <3

Comment: I'm my case, I was missing "x" on `import androidx.transition.TransitionInflater`

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the change [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#api-changes) it looks like it should probably read 'must' use support transitions rather than 'can' use them. Try changing your AutoTransition from android.transition.AutoTransition to android.support.transition.AutoTransition and it should work perfectly without needing any SDK version checks.

Answer (score 3):

check your fragment import like below..

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

if you used addSharedElement make change in app level gradle file api level 21.

```
     minSdkVersion 21
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using correct import and i cant set minSdkVersion to 21 because i need to support my app to lower api devices. Also the same code worked before build tools and support libraries update

Comment: that time you need to define annotation for particular method like     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

Comment: So what i need to do to make transitions work beginning with api19.

Comment: transitions will be work main things addSharedElement is need api 21.

Comment: i have added if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            ft.addSharedElement(view, "TransitionView");
but still get the exception

Comment: you can not show any fragment which transper. like HomeFragment fragment=new HomeFragment.

Comment: This is just abstract code. i have class which extends fragment which i am using.

Comment: Okay, i have changed to check from KITKAT to LOLLIPOP before creating the transition and everything is okay. But i dont understand why the same code worked properly with build tools version 26

Comment: Can you share you whole log ?
you should not face crash if you add following lins (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

Comment: As per your updated answer you are not getting exception ?

Comment: Yes, as I said, after changing from KITKAT to LOLLIPOP everything is okay. Just curious why it worked with earlier builds

Answer (score 1):

After switching to androidX, I got this error because some import was from

> android.package

and some from

> androidx.package

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using **MaterialContainerTransform** and I replaced

```
com.google.android.material.transition.platform
```

**by**

```
com.google.android.material.transition
```